# Microsoft Bot framework- Whatsapp integration

Tags: botframework, whatsapp, direct-line-botframework

I have an Azure hosted bot and I am trying to integrate it with WhatsApp.

I know that, as per the documentation, Whatsapp channel is not supported and I would have to enable directline for the integration.
I have enabled the directline channel.

Is there any way I can achieve this? If so, what are the steps I should follow for the integration?

Comment: How would you like to link WhatsApp? Via a provider? Out of interest, are you using C# or Node.js? An example of a direct line proxy for Google Assistant can be found [here](https://github.com/Capgemini-AIE/bot-framework-actions-on-google) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ailab/tree/master/GoogleAssistantConnector).

Comment: I would be using C#.

Comment: Twillio is supported by the BotFramework, and they have a way to integrate with WhatsApp. Last time I checked it was in beta, but that might be a good place to start.

Comment: I tried Twillio, created a bot on whatsapp but was not able to integrate my existing Azure bot with it.

Comment: There are also two adapters available from the BotBuilder Community repo. The first allows you to send and receive from WhatsApp via [InfoBip](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Infobip) and the second via [RingCentral](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.RingCentral). I don't know if they fully meet your needs, but they are other options you can test. If nothing else, you can reference them for building your own adapter.

Comment: I added MessageBird WhatsApp integration as an adapter, https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.MessageBird . It is easy to use and MessageBird has good pricing tiers.